# Centering a new page in a wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to center my program so that when it changes pages that it will remain centered.  As it stands now, it starts off centered, but when I change the page it is no longer centered.

I've tried using the following code, but it doesn't work for a page.  Thanks!

```
this.Left = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / 2) - (this.ActualWidth / 2);

this.Top = (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / 2) - (this.ActualHeight / 2);
```

Comment: where have you used this code snippet?

Comment: It works when I use it in the MainWindow, but it doesn't work when I try to use it for a page.

Comment: Unless this is just a splash screen I would find this extremely obnoxious as a user.

Comment: What you want to keep Centered ? your MainWindow or Page

Comment: The page.  The program switches between three pages of different sizes and they don't always end up in the center of the screen.  I see now that its a problem easily fixed if its a window, but this is a group project and we are using pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about Page but Window do have Property  WindowStartupLocation , This Property can have one of the three enum values 1)CenterScreen ,2) Manual , 3) CenterOwner , So if you want your MainWindow to be at Center of Screen then just set the property as

```
<myWindow:CustomPage x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myWindow="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.